# Text mask with jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way in jquery to do a mask for text?
For example i got slider with background, and I want to mask (hide) text which is going outside of background 
-(outside)-(limit)-text-(limit)-(outside)- and text is going in 2 way: left->right, and right-> left. (I want to hide text wich will go outsie the limit)
I can't do it by changeing width, becouse above is image
This is my slider class:

```
#slider-prod {
    float: left;
margin: 19px 0 0 67px;
width: 751px;
height: 257px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#slider-prod ul {}
#slider-prod ul li img {display: block;float: left;}
#slider-prod ul li{display: block;float: left;width: 751px;height: 257px;}
#slider-prod ul li p{    font-family:'Helvetica-BoldOblique';    text-shadow: 1px 0 1px #ffffff;
display: block;
float: left;
text-align: left;
line-height: 42px;
font-size: 15px;line-height: 19px;color: #204383}
#slider-prod ul li span{
    font-family:'Helvetica-BoldOblique';    text-shadow: 1px 0 1px #ffffff;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 42px;
    color: #ff7b00;
display: block;
float: left;
clear: both;

}
```

Comment: Please make a Fiddle or show us your code of what you have tried...

Answer (score 0):

This is done with the `overflow: hidden;` rule in CSS, not in Javascript.

Comment: Then wrap the text in its own div